# saving and recovering .csv files on mac vs pc

Tags: python, csv

I am taking a python for finance course and it is having me save and recover .csv files for data files to use and I can't think of mac equivalent for the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv('D:/Python/New_Files/example_01.csv', index_col = 'Date')
```

instead of D: I typed download since that's the only choice i have on my mac

```
new_data.to_csv('Downloads:/Python/New_Files/example_01.csv')
data = pd.read_csv('D:/Python/New_Files/example_01.csv', index_col = 'Date')
```

Comment: Mac has a Unix based file system. So there's no concept of a C or D drive. Instead, there's a hierarchical file system with `/` as the root, and then files and directories underneath it, such as `/Users/username/Downloads/example_01.csv`. If you're new to Mac, you might want to take advantage of some of the [educational materials](https://support.apple.com/explore/new-to-mac) out there.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, you can use `~` and `pathlib`'s `expanduser()` method to get to your home directory:

```
import pathlib

location = pathlib.Path('~/Downloads/Python/New_Files/example_01.csv').expanduser()
data = pd.read_csv(location, index_col = 'Date')
```